# Topologies on a finite set with more than $5$ elements.

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $X$ is a finite set with more than $5$ elements. Which of the following is **true**.
>
> 1. There is a topology on $X$ which is $T_3$.
> 2. There is a topology on $X$ which is $T_2$ but not $T_3$.
> 3. There is a topology on $X$ which is $T_1$ but not $T_2$.
> 4. There is no topology on $X$ which is $T_1$

First how to determine which topology is there? Since it is a finite set, so the topologies are a subset of $P(X)$, power set of $X$. We can consider the discrete topology. What are other kind of topologies we can consider so it match with the given options. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: This is a weird question...the "more than 5 elements" condition is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @eric that's what i also thought. It is there just to add confusion.

Comment: @Eric: It may also be because the topologies on sets with 4 or fewer elements have previously been completely classified, and the reader ia being asked to generalize or break the generalization for other finite cardinalities.

Comment: Does $T_3$ imply $T_1$ in your definition. Or is it only being able to separate a closed set from a point?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $T_3$ is regular, isn't it? Separate a closed set from a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $X$ is finite, you should try to figure out what a $T_1$ topology on $X$ can look like. This should fully allow you to evaluate all four of the proposed statements.

Comment: Ok so if i am considering a discrete topology then as it satisfy all separation axioms so option 1 is true. Right?

Comment: Yes, the first statement is true. What about the others?

Comment: I am only considering discrete topology, I don't know any other topology on a finite set which is $T_1$.

Comment: In fact, one can prove that if a topology on a finite set is $T_1,$ then it *must* be discrete.

Comment: Given that result (which I leave to you to prove), can you determine if the other three statements are true, false, or undetermined?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.

Comment: Ok provided I can prove the result, we can readily get rid of option 4,3,2.

Comment: Nicely concluded! Good luck with the proof, and let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

A $X$ is a finite $T_1$ space, every singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed. As closed sets are closed under finite unions, *all* subsets of $X$ are closed and so all subsets of $X$ are also open. Hence $X$ is discrete.

Nr 4. Is false: the discrete topology is $T_1$. If $X$ is finite and $T_2$ or $T_1$, it will be at least $T_1$ so discrete and  $T_3,T_2, T_1$ as well. So 2 and 3 are false. 1 is true as the discrete topology again is an example. The number 5 is irrelevant,  finiteness is all that matters.